# In Ember.js, how can I change the sort order of a filtered model in an ArrayController?

Tags: sorting, ember.js

Here's an example:

http://jsbin.com/joqod/4/edit?html,js,output

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();


App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;



App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("things");
});


App.Thing = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});


App.ThingsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  
  queryParams: ['status'],
  
  status: "all",
  
  sortAscending: "true",
  
   filteredThings: function() {
     console.log("Inside filteredThings()");
     var things = this.get('model');
     var status = this.get('status');
     
     switch (status) {
       case "open":
         console.log("status is open");
         return things.filterBy('status', 'open').sortBy('name');
       case "closed":
         console.log("status is closed");
         return things.filterBy('status', 'closed').sortBy('name');
       case "all":
         console.log("status is all");
         return things.sortBy('name');
     }
   }.property('model', 'status')
});


App.ThingsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('thing');
  }
});


App.Thing.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: "f",
    status: "open"
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "e",
    status: "open"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "d",
    status: "open"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "c",
    status: "closed"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "b",
    status: "closed"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "a",
    status: "closed"
  },
];
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//builds.handlebarsjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="//builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.7.0/ember.js"></script>
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/beta/ember-data.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  <p>This is the application template.</p>

<ul>
<li>{{#link-to 'things' (query-params status="all")}}All Things{{/link-to}}</li>

<li>{{#link-to 'things' (query-params status="closed")}}Closed Things{{/link-to}}</li>

<li>{{#link-to 'things' (query-params status="open")}}Open Things{{/link-to}}</li>
</ul>


{{outlet}}
</script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">

  <p>This is the index template.</p>
  
{{outlet}}
</script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="things">
<div>
  {{#each thing in filteredThings}}
    <p>{{thing.id}} {{thing.name}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</div>
  
{{outlet}}
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Depending on the query params, I want to filter a model and then change the sort order.  I'm able to return the filtered model, but have been unable to change the sort order at all.  I tried copying the model, modifying the existing model. . . .  I stumbled upon this, http://emberjs.com/api/#method_computed_sort , but don't know if that's overkill or just a bad idea.

P.S.  The example doesn't mess with query params.  Was just trying to get the sort working in a simple example before applying it to my existing code containing query params, which seems to work fine.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the filteredModel shows as sorted for me?

Comment: @Mike1o1  Thanks, Mike.  Yeah, I messed up trying to keep this in sync with the jsbin.  :-)  Sorry about that.  I am updating the jsbin now.  I was able to apply a sort, but I was unable to change the 'sortAscending' property.  Trying to illustrate that in jsbin now.

Comment: Okay, it's a little more accurate now.  You can see (unless I'm mistaken) that changing the ThingsController's sortAscending property doesn't affect the sort order of the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this, but here is how I solved this.

First, I modified your `filteredThings` property to only filter the items and not try to sort. Then, I created a computed property to sort the results of that filter based on the status. Then, I created an observable property to listen to changes in the `status` and set the `sortProperty` there.

See updated [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/gobalo/16/). Again, not sure if there are better ways, but this is how I solved the problem.

(Clicking on closed sets descending order).

**Update**: You don't actually need the observable property. You can set sortProperties in your filteredThings property. Then, just bind to "sortedThings", which is a computed property off the filteredThings property. See updated [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/gobalo/18/edit).

Comment: Well!  Ember.computed.sort seemed to do the trick.  Can't say I completely understand.  :-) Particularly since I can't find any reference in the guides to using sortProperties in this manner, but it works, so I'm leaving it alone.  Thanks a lot for your help, @Mike1o1 .

Comment: The way I understand it is that the ArrayController is just a proxy to the underlying array. You have to tell it how you want it to sort. Just doing this.get('model').sortBy('name') might give you a sorted array, but that isn't what the #each helper is binding to.